# How to use a proxy in the SharpSVN client

Tags: svn, proxy, sharpsvn

i use SharpSVN in my app to check out a repository from a http server. I'm behind a firewall and need to use a proxy server to connect.

Can i set this and when, where is it?

Thanks.
Andreas

Answer (score 2):

If you use the default configuration (E.g. not setting your own config directory) Subversion stores its settings in `%APPDATA%\Subversion` and in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion`. If you set your settings there they will be automatically applied via SharpSvn.

You could use a tool like AnkhSVN or TortoiseSVN to edit the registry settings via a GUI. They share these same setting locations.

It is possible to programmatically override these settings from SharpSvn if necessary, but using the central settings is in most cases much easier.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers for details on what to configure in the files.